# Update in Subselects of an Insert

Tags: sql

is it possible to place an Update Query into a subselect of an Insert Query?
Like:

```
select * from db.testtable
where
col1 = 1 or
(UPDATE ...);
```

Comment: What you are looking for? Explain problem because this is not the solution.

Comment: Perhaps you are talking about `update ... where not exists ( select ... )`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your DB engine you can do something like

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```

to avoid duplicates and update instead.